# Java SimpleDateFormat conversion minute error

Tags: java, datetime

I've got a problem during the conversion of a Date object between two different formats.

These are the dateFormats

```
private final SimpleDateFormat sdf_input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ", Locale.ITALY);
private final SimpleDateFormat sdf_output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ITALY);
```

this is the code I use to convert from the input string to the output string

```
Date tmp = sdf_input.parse(timestamp);
this.timestamp = sdf_output.format(tmp);
System.out.println("CONVERSIONE: "+timestamp+" -> "+this.timestamp);
```

And this is the output of the execution

```
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:01:59.652546+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:51Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:01:59.652612+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:51Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:01:59.652452+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:51Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:01:59.867481+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:26Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.102929+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.102861+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.102660+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.102995+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.102788+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.103056+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.209643+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:29Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.232735+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:52Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.231628+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:51Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.232609+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:52Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.232808+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:52Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.231775+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:51Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.280670+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:40Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.281655+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:41Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.282772+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.281788+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:41Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.282871+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.282629+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.505474+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:25Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.505653+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:25Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.506724+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:26Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.506792+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:26Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.505589+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:25Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.506578+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:26Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:04.561530+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:25Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:05.845597+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:10Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:09.981509+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:18:30Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:12.329653+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:07:41Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:14.305630+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:07:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:14.305480+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:07:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:14.305565+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:07:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:15.364254+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.243355+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.243537+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.243424+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.243482+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.473340+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:09Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.473424+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:09Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:16.533370+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:09Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:19.046342+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:05Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:19.719421+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:18Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:19.719319+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:18Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:19.719555+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:18Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:20.797860+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:15:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:25.528294+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:25.528375+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:25.528439+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:25.528505+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:25.528592+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:25.529306+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:26.139847+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:45Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:26.257798+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:28.101521+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:09Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:28.432787+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:40Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:28.684613+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:52Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:28.765876+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:15:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:28.846772+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:34Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:29.341246+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:10Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:29.341335+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:10Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:29.342104+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:11Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:29.351248+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:20Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:29.351337+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:20Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:29.351405+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:20Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:30.498554+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:48Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:31.512218+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:03Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:35.997197+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:35.997292+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:35.997416+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:35.997355+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:36.001226+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:02:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:36.001360+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:02:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:36.860512+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:56Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:38.025692+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:03Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:38.045314+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:23Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.099268+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.099640+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.099489+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.099569+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.109191+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:31Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.109270+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:31Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:42.204322+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:06Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:43.480420+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.327143+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:11Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.680299+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:04Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:43.480171+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:43.480259+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:43.480315+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:43.480366+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:43.790065+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:15:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.030157+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.030273+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.030334+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.030410+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:03:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.330137+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.680127+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:04Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.680189+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:04Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.680242+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:04Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.680355+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:04Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:44.680411+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:04Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:46.404120+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:30Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:46.404204+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:30Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:46.410121+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:36Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:46.706104+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:14:32Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:47.300106+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:07:47Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:47.300187+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:07:47Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:47.325128+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:47.547784+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:54Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:47.563866+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:10Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.125137+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.125343+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.125249+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.129176+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:57Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.129336+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:57Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.129404+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:57Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.425121+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.425248+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.429186+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:57Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.435138+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:03Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.439145+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:07Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:48.439290+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:07Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.505166+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.505236+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:14Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.506094+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:15Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.510105+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:19Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.508244+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:17Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.511108+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:20Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.895285+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:17:44Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.895104+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:17:44Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.895219+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:17:44Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.898104+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:17:47Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.898256+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:17:47Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:49.898327+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:17:47Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:50.829374+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:50.829142+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:50.829249+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:50.829315+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:50.829434+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:50.829495+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.227234+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:39Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.329286+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.357248+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:08:49Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.389289+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.414304+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:46Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.414419+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:46Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.460243+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:32Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.460380+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:32Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.460454+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:10:32Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.568355+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:20Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.568231+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:20Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.569322+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:12:21Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.794367+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:06Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.794137+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:06Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.794294+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:16:06Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:52.917557+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:18:09Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.080141+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.080370+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.080448+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.417696+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:50Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.529258+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.529127+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:42Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.530181+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.530353+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.530434+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:43Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:53.539135+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:11:52Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.632057+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:27Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.632159+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:27Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.642357+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.642070+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.642217+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.642285+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:13:37Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.992441+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:27Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.992227+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:27Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.992364+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:27Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.992525+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:27Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.993183+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:55.993304+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:19:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.092556+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.092236+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.092473+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.092630+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.092697+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.092764+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:04:28Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.197311+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.196207+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.196353+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.196427+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.196510+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:12Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.197182+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:06:13Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.417433+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.416196+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:52Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.417204+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.417360+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:53Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.418194+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:54Z
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:56.418337+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:09:54Z
```

As you can see I've got an issue with the minute but I don't understand the cause of this problem.
Someone of you can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your input appears to have four digits of milliseconds; there are only three digits from `0` to `999` (and one thousand milliseconds is one second).

Answer (score 5):

Problem is with milliseconds, you can only have three input digits.

```
CONVERSIONE: 2016-06-23T18:02:00.232808+0200 -> 2016-06-23T18:05:52Z
```

Program thinks there are 232808 milliseconds ~ 232 seconds = 3 min 52 sec, and that is what you (wrongly) get in addition.

---

How to resolve your problem? Use classes from [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package which is included in Java 8. It supports precision up to nanoseconds. From the docs for [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html):

> LocalTime is an immutable date-time object that represents a time,
>   often viewed as hour-minute-second. Time is represented to nanosecond
>   precision. For example, the value "13:45.30.123456789" can be stored
>   in a LocalTime.

Answer (score 0):

The Java docs for Java 8 as seen from the mentioned link, tell us that the Millisecond component is having a length of 3 integers: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Thus in your input, you have to enter only 3 integers for the millisecond component.